# How to use Adpative banner ads of Google Ad-mob in xamarin.forms app?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, admob

I am implementing google's ad-mob in my Xamarin.Forms application and I have used Marctron's plugin to show ads in my app: https://github.com/marcojak/MTAdmob

It works fine with Smart banner ads but if I want to use Adaptive banner ads it's not working. I have done R&D on it but not get any solution. Does anyone know how to implement Adaptive banner
ads in Xamarin.Froms?

Why Adaptive banner?

An adaptive banner makes better use of the available screen size. Plus:

- It uses a provided width rather than full screen width, enabling you
  to account for display cutouts .
- It selects an optimal height for the specific device, rather than
  having a constant height across different sized devices, mitigating
  the effects of device fragmentation.

To show ads I have used this code:

**In Xaml page:**

```cs
<ads:MTAdView />
```

---

**In App.xaml**

```cs
<Style TargetType = "ads:MTAdView">
    <Setter Property = "BackgroundColor" Value = "White" />
    <Setter Property = "PersonalizedAds" Value = "true" />
    <Setter Property = "AdsId" Value = "{x:Static helpers:AdConfigHelper.BannerAdUnitId}" />
    <Setter Property = "IsVisible" Value = "true" />
    <Setter Property = "HeightRequest">
    <Setter.Value >
        <OnPlatform x: TypeArguments = "x:Double" Phone="50" Tablet="90" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```